# Are these String operations equivalent in Java and Python?

Tags: java, python, string, performance, replace

Consider the following two code blocks,
http://ideone.com/3nNdVs

```
String[] matches = new String[] {"Foo", "Bar"};
long start = System.nanoTime();
for(int i=0; i< 1000000; i++) {
    String name = "This String is Foo Bar";
    for (String s : matches){
        name = name.replace(s, "");
    }
}
System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - start)/1000000);
```

and http://ideone.com/v8wg6m

```
matches = {"Foo", "Bar"}
start = time.time()
for x in xrange(1000000):
    name = "This String is Foo Bar"
    for s in matches:
        name = name.replace(s, "")
print time.time() - start
```

While trying to benchmark the performance of these two, I found that the one implemented in Java takes about 50% longer than the Python. This came as quite a shock to me as i was expecting the Python version to be slower.

So the first question is, are there better or faster ways to perform these two functions?

Second, if not, why is the Java version slower than the Python one?

Comment: *"Are these String operations equivilent in Java and Python?"* Well...no...the Python version does replacements (`matches` has "Foo" and "Bar"), the Java version doesn't (`matches` does not have "Foo" or "Bar").

Comment: btw, iterations on set is slow than list and tuples, and your codes are not equivalent.

Comment: `matches = {"Foo", "Bar"}` is a set; you almost certainly want a list: `matches = ["Foo", "Bar"]`.

Comment: Languages don't have speed, they have only semantics. If you want to compare speed you must choose specific implementations to compare. If you want to do some performance testing to see a bit more under the hood on *nix based computers you can use perf stat -B (sudo apt-get install linux-tools-common linux-base)

Comment: I'm going to link to this, because it seems relevant: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: In my computer the Python is slower (1106 on average of 5 runs) compared to Java (999.2 on average of 5 runs), although if you change `"PS3", "Game"` in Java into `"Foo", "Bar"`, Java is slower (1182.5 on average of 5 runs)

Comment: T.J and Justhalf, sorry that was an error, in my posting the problem, in my actual tests the matching words were both foo bar.

Comment: Grijesh and Delnan, I see, but then that will make the python faster still, i am trying to understand why it is faster in this instant at all.

Comment: YFP and Mikkel, im not sure what exactly you are trying to tell me in either of your comments. YFP, im not asking in general why one language would be faster than an other. i have two examples i believed to be comparable. Mikkel, im not sure if your comment is addressed to me. but as i see it, i have already established that in my environment one is quite a a fair bit faster than the other. im trying to understand why.

Comment: FYI Delnan and Grijesh, changing to a list upped the speed difference to python being almost 75% faster

Comment: @user779420 Can you please post the code with ideone.com links, so that people can compare the results?

Comment: @user779420 In my machine, Python is slightly faster than Java... Like 30% faster.

Comment: @thefourtheye thanks, but my tests all show that python is faster too which surprised me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the reason that python was quicker, it is because the .replace method in java uses regex which is compiled every time you call .replace.

there are many quicker alternatives, but the one that i found to be most convinient is to use org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils library's .replaceEach which uses index of to find and replace substrings which i understand is still faster than a one time compiled regex.

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
for(int i=0; i< 1000000; i++) {
    String name = "This String is Foo Bar";
    name = StringUtils.replaceEach(name, matches, replaces);
}
System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - start)/1000000);
```

unfortunatly i cany provide a link on ide one as they dont have apache commons.

This version of the algorithm on my system was about 1/4 faster than the .replace method and about 1/2 faster than the python.

if anyone has a faster option for python let me know

thanks

Comment: That's definitely why the Java one is slow. If you knew at compile time what the regex's you wanted to replace were, you could use Pattern.compile("Foo"), Pattern.compiile("Bar") to save some time.

Comment: @theSilentOne yep your right, but i think the indexof solution would still be faster than the compiled regex. if the strings were longer or more complex, then regex would defiantly be the way to go

Answer (score -1):

For Python use the timeit module:

```
import timeit

setup = """
matches = {'Foo', 'Bar'}
for x in xrange(1000000):
  name = 'This String is Foo Bar'
  for s in matches:
    name = name.replace(s, '')
"""

print min(timeit.Timer(setup=setup).repeat(10))
```

Comment: sorry Jeff, but i dont know that that really helps me get any closer to an answer.

Comment: @user779420: Jeff is perfectly right in one aspect: You're measuring some timing having no relevance whatsoever. In Java you need something like [caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper) or [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh) when you want to get figures related to real performance.

Comment: strings are immutable. Every time you do a loop you are creating copies of the string. s.replace creates a copy also. The following is consistently performing better: ''.join([x for x in 'This String is Foo Bar'.split() if x not in ('Foo', 'Bar')])

Comment: @Jeff Bond Actually it seems to me that the replace is faster than the join http://ideone.com/MCrDGs